# How do I set the state of a three-state checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, autoit

I am using AutoIt to automate a Windows application for testing. I would like to be able to set the state of a three state checkbox that is by default indeterminate.

I have tried using `ControlCommand(.., .., .., "Uncheck", ..)` to set the "unchecked" state but it remains at indeterminate.

When I use "Check" in `ControlCommand` it moves the CheckBox from Indeterminate to False because that is the order of clicks:

1. Indeterminate
2. Unchecked
3. Checked

Is there a way to set the state programatically using AutoIt, without assuming the default state and counting the number of clicks myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Checkbox is in fact a special version of a button. Don't ask why, it's MS and they thought that was a good idea.

You can do exactly what you want using the `_GUICtrlButton_SetCheck` function, there is an example in the helpfile [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GUICtrlButton_SetCheck.htm):

```
_GUICtrlButton_SetCheck($idChk, $BST_INDETERMINATE)
```